# Combining Cypher results with APOC SQL queries

Tags: sql, neo4j, subquery, cypher

I am trying to update node properties of a PostgreSQL database that I have running in a virtual environment. I am building a Jazz knowledge base and would like to use the node ids to query additional properties from the PSQL database using APOC.

I have tried unwinding the ids and using them to run the SQL statements with APOC.

This is the code I have tried thus far:

```
MATCH (a:Artist)
WHERE a.genre = 'jazz'
WITH COLLECT(a.mbid) AS ids
UNWIND ids AS id
CALL apoc.load.jdbc('myDB',
"select DISTINCT a.gid, ar.name as country FROM artist a INNER JOIN area ar on a.area = ar.id WHERE a.gid = ?", [id]) YIELD row
MATCH (a:Artist) WHERE a.mbid = row.gid SET a.country = row.country
RETURN COUNT(a.country)
```

I am running into an error saying "ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying". Is there anyway to use the ids from the Cypher query to update each node individually through individual SQL statements with APOC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `gid` column is a UUID type in your Postgres database and that the error is when executing the query via `apoc.load.jdbc`, the following explicit casts of your IDs in the SQL should at least have the comparison work and have the query return a string value you can compare on:

```
MATCH (a:Artist)
WHERE a.genre = 'jazz'
WITH COLLECT(a.mbid) AS ids
UNWIND ids AS id
CALL apoc.load.jdbc('myDB',
"select DISTINCT a.gid::text, ar.name as country FROM artist a INNER JOIN area ar on a.area = ar.id WHERE a.gid = UUID(?)", [id]) YIELD row
MATCH (a:Artist) WHERE a.mbid = row.gid SET a.country = row.country
RETURN COUNT(a.country)
```

Comment: This worked! I don't know why we use UUID(?), but I could implement it no problem. Thanks!